# Compare two array of string using c# or javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have the two string array name str_arr1[],str_arr2[]. The two array having same or different value.

```
str_arr1[] = { "one", "two", "three","four","Doctor","Engineer","Driver" };
str_arr2[] = { "one", "Doctor","Engineer" };
```

Usually str_arr1[] having more record compare to str_arr2[]. I want to check the str_arr1[] having str_arr2[]. If it's true means return true. Otherwise return false.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool contains = !str_arr2.Except(str_arr1).Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  return arr1.sort().join() == arr2.sort().join();
}
var arr1 = ["one", "two", "three","four","Doctor","Engineer","Driver" ];
var arr2 = ["one", "Doctor","Engineer"];

    console.log(compareArrays(arr1,arr2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this

```
static bool ArraysEqual<T>(T[] a1, T[] a2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(a1,a2))
        return true;

    if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
        return false;

    if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
        return false;

    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(a1[i], a2[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool result=str_arr2.Any(x=>!str_arr1.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str_arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "Doctor", "Engineer", "Driver" };
        var str_arr2 = new string[] { "one", "Doctor", "Engineer" };

        return str_arr1.Intersect(str_arr2).Count() == str_arr2.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inter = str_arr1.Intersect( str_arr2);

foreach (var s in inter)
{
    Console.WriteLine("present" + s); // or you can return somthin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not cleared the conditions. I am combining all the conditions in this.

```
 string[] str_arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "Doctor", "Engineer", "Driver" };
 string[] str_arr2 = new string[] { "one", "aaaa", "yyy" };

 bool contains = !str_arr2.Except(str_arr1).Any(); // this will show true only if all the items of str_arr2 are in str_arr1 

 bool result = str_arr2.Any(x => !str_arr1.Contains(x));// this will show true if any of the items of str_arr2 are in str_arr1
```